# ui-routing for angular using $stateparams and trying to send data

Tags: angular

Okay, this is what I got so far https://embed.plnkr.co/QtM3ucPn6R1cPgdPjEzp/ .
I am trying to put information on the about me page, through **$stateParams**. 
With a name and a nickname, In the state from about I gave the controller this  **expect($stateParams).toBe({meId : 1});** and I gave the url this **url : '/about/{meId}',**. So on the page from about I want to give the state some information about me like my nickname and my name. So the id I gave for the information is 1. because the **expect($stateParams).toBe({meId : 1});** is 1. I want to let the page get the meId 1. with the nickname and the name with it.

I tried a few different things like the data and params, but both didn't work like they should so what am I doing wrong right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement here is quite ambiguous. From what I have understood, you need to show set of values from controller based on the `$stateParams` value.

See [forked plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lnkvxbsu3b6tDfGcdehx?p=preview)

```
.state('about',{
    url : '/about/{meId}',
      templateUrl : 'about.html',
      controller: function($stateParams, $scope){
        if($stateParams.meId == 1) {
           $scope.meId = {
             id: $stateParams.meId,
             naam: 'audrey',
             nickname: 'audi'
           }
        }
      }
  });
```

Moreover, `expect($stateParams).toBe({meId : 1});` is a Jasmine unit testing framework syntax for unit tests and is irrelevant here.